# Change nested for loops into a do-while loop

Tags: c++

How do I change this into a do-while loop? I am trying to have the exact the same output as the code posted here, but I want to use  do-while loop instead of for loop

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int side;

    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> side;

    for (int i = 0; i < side; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            cout << "#";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Briefly explain what you are trying to do

Comment: Why do you want to? Is there something wrong with what you have?

Comment: What I did is a while loop but I am trying change it into do while loop but I cannot figure it out

Comment: There is no sense at all in changing this into a while or do-while loop. As you can see in the answers, the code just gets longer and more convoluted.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int side;

    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> side;

    int i = 0;

    do {
       int j = i;

       while(j >= 0){
         std::cout << "#";
         j--;
       }

       std::cout << "\n";

       i++;
    }
    while(i < side);
}
```

Is this what you meant? - Do While Loop

Comment: Yes but this does not have the same output as the original one

Comment: forget to add a newline

Comment: Thank you so much for your help this helps a lot for me to understand the loop